# PHP - Check $_POST array for specific duplicate values with different keys

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have a HTML form that gets pre-populated with data from a DB. It is used to update the cells with an input field and the user can click 'Save' to post the form to an update script. Example below:

[image]

The rows 'Lidnummer' to 'Woonplaats' are just updates through a normal UPDATE query. No problem there. The problem lies in the 'Telefoonnummer' (phone numbers in english) rows. The phone number table in my DB consists of the Primary Key 'telefoonnummer' and Foreign Key 'lidnummer', So it is not possible to update 'Telefoonnummer' because of this.

To get around this I want to delete the old 'telefoonnumer' and replace it with the new one and to do this I have placed a hidden input field containing the old number in the form.

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="telefoonnummer' . $num . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($subrow[$db_column]) . '" required></td>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="oud-telnr' . $num . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($subrow[$db_column]) . '">';
```

For example I submitted above form and placed NEW behind all the phone number. Note that below every 'NEW' phone number is the old one because of the hidden form field.

```
Array
(
    [lidnummer] => 3
    [naam] => Kocken
    [voornaam] => Sjoerd
    [huisnummer] => 1-hoog
    [postcode] => 6542GT
    [telefoonnummer1] => +311085467985 NEW
    [oud-telnr1] => +311085467985
    [telefoonnummer2] => +31645785426 NEW
    [oud-telnr2] => +31645785426
    [telefoonnummer3] => +317258546546 NEW
    [oud-telnr3] => +317258546546
)
```

**Now here is the thing:**
I want to compare ONLY the phone numbers in this POST array that have the same number in the KEY to eachother. So in this case I want to compare the values from 'telefoonnummer1' with 'oud-telnr1' and 'telefoonnummer2' with 'oud-telnr2' and so forth. If they are different I want to use those values and if they are the same then don't do anything.

The part where I am stuck is on how to compare only a set of values in this array with eachother. Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this? (or maybe a better way on how to do this in general?)

**EDIT** What I haven't mentioned is that the number of phone numbers could change. So it could be any number. I need to achieve this so that it works regardles of the number of 'telefoonnummers'

Comment: `if($array['telefoonnummer1'] != $array['oud-telnr1']) { do something }`? (Or I am misunderstanding the question)

Comment: Yeah that would work if there is only 1 telefoonnummer to change. I don't know how many phone numbers one could have

Comment: But you seem to know how many there are using `$num`, right? Use a `for` loop then.

Comment: Hmm haven't thought about that because $num was only used in the form to differentiate the phone numbers and it was not in the part that I use for updating. I added it as another hidden field and currently trying to make it work. Could be something here! Thanks a lot!